# Can I reprogram the key-less entry code on a Ford F150 without the original code?

Tags: ford, keyless-entry

My neighbor has a 2004 F150 with the key-less entry system.  He purchased it at an auction (it was a repossession), and didn't get the code.

Short of taking it to the dealer (they want to charge 1 hr labor to reset it) is there a way to reprogram the code?

Answer (score 2):

Ford has the code in a few different places depending on year and model, but I think for a 2004 F150, it is on the back wall behind the drivers seat. They also sometimes write it out on the lock module itself. Hope that helps a little.

Comment: To clarify: With the Ford factory 5-button keypad systems, you can't program a personal code without knowing the factory code. However, the factory code is printed on the keyless entry module. Once you have it, to program a personal code, follow the instructions in the owner's manual, e.g. [PDF] http://www.motorcraftservice.com/pubs/content/~WO4F12/~MUS~LEN/36/04f12og5e.pdf#page=94 (2004 Ford F-150 USA Owner's guide 5e, p. 94)

Answer (score 1):

Please also note that the entry code *cannot* be reprogrammed. It is more-or-less `burned` into the module. This is true of all fords.  This module is called a `GEM` or `RAP`, depending on your model and vintage.

GEM - Generic Electronics Module.
RAP - Remote AntiTheft Personality

If you wish to change the code, you have to replace this module to do so.